# Books about four people with telekinetic powers set in the future

Tags: story-identification, books, telekinesis

This book is set in the future (unsure how far) in the U.S., and it was in an outskirts city. The main character is a girl, and she learns that she has telekinetic powers, and these powers also keep her from being harmed from any sort of danger, except anything made from a certain material (titanium, I believe), and there are three others like her, all with a different weakness. The girl goes to a small school with two of the bad guys, and after learning of her abilities they try to kill her. The plot is really involved, so I can't get to it deeply on here.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. With our `story-identification` we normally recommend [not holding back on spoilers](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10797/im-asking-a-story-id-question-should-i-include-spoilers), as the people reading and answering your question will either have read the story or be ready to accept spoilers, I suggest you give us all the details you can to help us better identify your story. Take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to see if you can [edit] in any more details

Comment: What is an "outskirts city"? Outskirts of what? Do you mean it's a suburb of a bigger city?

Comment: Unrelated, but it's funny how the bad guys always attend the same school as the protagonist!

Comment: Do you remember anything about how she gained her telekinesis or was she born with it?

Comment: @user14111 It is an outskirts city to a protected city. It is protected by a big bubble basically to keep it sheltered from the changing climate of the earth.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like [*Pulse*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/14760527-pulse) by Patrick Carman. It is the first book of the [*Pulse* trilogy](https://www.goodreads.com/series/80931-pulse).

> With the help of her mysterious classmate Dylan Gilmore, Faith Daniels discovers that she can move objects with her mind. This telekinetic ability is called a “pulse,” and Dylan has the talent, too.
>
> In riveting action scenes, Faith demonstrates her ability to use her pulse against a group of telekinesis masters who are so powerful they can flatten their enemies by uprooting streetlights, throwing boulders, and changing the course of a hurtling hammer so that it becomes a deadly weapon. But even with her unusual talent, the mind--and the heart--can be difficult to control. If Faith wants to join forces with Dylan and save the world, she’ll have to harness the power of both.
>
> Patrick Carman’s Pulse trilogy is a stunning and epic triumph about the power of the mind--and of love.

Comment: I've edited in some basic information, could you [edit] to explain how this matches the OPs description?